# initialize json file data as a TypeScript Map

Tags: json, typescript

as a young typescript padawan
i am trying to parse mock data from a json witch involves initializing a Map<string, MenuPageData>
and i get an error (attached below)
i would like to be able to supply the correct data format in the json or map it properly from the existing data.

here is the error:
[image]

here is the code:

```
export interface MenuItem {
    data: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        currency?: string;
        imageUrl?: string;
        description?: string;
        price?: number;
    };
}
export interface MenuPageData {
    pageName: string;
    menuItems: MenuItem[];
}
export interface MenuPageDataCollection {
    menuPages: Map<string, MenuPageData>;
}
```

the error is comming from "(pagesDataMock.menuPages)"

```
const dataCollection: MenuPageDataCollection = { menuPages: new Map<string, MenuPageData>(pagesDataMock.menuPages) };

export const menuPagesCollection: () => MenuPageDataCollection = (): MenuPageDataCollection => {  
return dataCollection;
};
```

and here is the json source:

```
{
"menuPages": [
    "mealPage1",
    {
        "pageName": "menuPage1",
        "menuItems": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": "null0",
                    "name": "meal",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "imageUrl": "../images/greenHand.jpg",
                    "description": "tasty",
                    "price": 12
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": "null0",
                    "name": "meal",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "imageUrl": "../images/greenHand.jpg",
                    "description": "tasty",
                    "price": 12
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "mealPage2",
    {
        "pageName": "menuPage1",
        "menuItems": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": "null0",
                    "name": "meal",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "imageUrl": "../images/greenHand.jpg",
                    "description": "tasty",
                    "price": 12
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": "null0",
                    "name": "meal",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "imageUrl": "../images/greenHand.jpg",
                    "description": "tasty",
                    "price": 12
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

i would appreciate and feedback, i tried several different ways of doing it but now 3-4 days passed by and i am running on empty of understanding

Comment: Do you have control over the json structure?

Comment: under poc so yes.

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0326534/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) is a rather strong constraint that is not representable in JSON [as is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#full_json_syntax). First you'll have to validate the input is satisfying the requirements for your `Map<string, MenuPageData>`. Then to make it understandable by TS wrap in into [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or [type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) function. And finally convert it into the actual [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object yourself.

Simplified example:

```ts
interface IFace {
    prop: string
}

interface Res {
    title: string
    ifaceMap: Map<string, IFace>
}

interface ResJSON {
    title: string
    ifaceMap: { [K in string]: IFace }
}


function assertResponse(json: unknown): asserts json is ResJSON {
  ...
}

function convert2Res(res: ResJSON): Res {
    const { title, ifaceMap } = res
    const map = new Map()

    for(let key in ifaceMap) map.set(key, ifaceMap[key])

    return { title, ifaceMap: map }
}

assertResponse(goodResponse)
const mapRes = convert2Res(goodResponse)
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3KQw)

---

In case you have full control of the source json and absolutely sure it may never be misshaped you may completely skip the `assert` part and feed the response (forcibly asserted to `ResJSON` type) right into `convert2Res`.